# UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER doesn't show back button, doesn't do swipe to back: UIKIT

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Hey Guys I am trying to use NavigationController for back button and swipe left to back action.

can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Could u tell me what else to do ?
P.S. Show instead of present doesn't work as well.

```
     let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: BarcodeViewController())  
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   present(vc, animated: false)
```

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: It's unclear. The viewcontrollers of the navigationcontroller will have the back. Here, we only see one vc: `BarcodeViewController`, so there is no "next vc", so no back from that second vc to `BarcodeViewController`.

Comment: I mean present the barcodeview comtroller from the default viewcontroller we get when creatimg the app

Comment: There's no such thing as "deafult VC". The app shows whatever you implement it to show. Anyway, you modally presented a navigation controller over something. Unless you push a second VC on top of the navigation controller's root view controller (a `BarcodeViewController` in your example), you won't see the Back button, because there's nothing to return to.

Comment: Got you thanks. any advice how to implement in default view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this problem by embedding main ViewController in SceneDelegate and then push a new viewController via  UINavigationController.pushViewController ..